# Shall I centralize an association of subclasses in their superclass?

Tags: database-design, uml, entity-relationship, class-diagram, erd

I have one parent entity class called `User` and 2 child entity classes, `Member` and `Tenant`, and I have another entity class called `Complain`. Now both `Member` and `Tenant` can create `Complain`. In this case, shall I add an association directly between the child entity classes and `Complain` or shall I add it between `User` (the parent of both) and between `Complain`? Which one of the following diagrams is correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: So each of your user has exactly one complain(t)? That can't be right?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends on the intended meaning of your association with the class `Complaint`. If any (potential) user has such an association, then you should centralize it in the `User` class, as in your diagram 1. Otherwise, or if you are not sure about this, better keep the association distributed among the two subclasses `Member` and `Tenant`, as in your diagram 2.

Comment: The idea is one Complaint  can be created by one User (Member or Tenant) and will be handled by other User (again Member or Tenant). So in this case shall I stick with the centralized association?

Comment: If you are sure that the association is characteristic for any normal type of user (including potential future user types), then it's better to cntralize it.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I appreciated your help!!